# How can i increase the performance between Access and Excel with this VBA Code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

i want to increase the performance of this code:

```
Dim...
...
...
...
...


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Dateipfad\Dateiname.xlsx", True)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select DataPointVID from My_ValidReport", dbOpenSnapshot)

Do Until rs.EOF = True
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Set ValidMeldeposition = ws.UsedRange.Cells.Find(What:=rs!DataPointVID)
        If Not (ValidMeldeposition Is Nothing) Then ValidMeldeposition.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    Next ws
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

j = 0
Do While Dir(Dokumentenpfad) <> ""
    j = j + 1
    Dokumentenpfad = CurrentProject.Path & "\Dateiname" & Format(Date, " dd.mm.yyyy") & " (" & j & ")" & ".xlsx"
Loop

NeuerReport = Dokumentenpfad

wb.SaveCopyAs (NeuerReport)
MsgBox "Your file was saved here: " & vbCrLf & "'" & NeuerReport & "'"
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

The problem is that the Excelfile contains over 70 Worksheets and every Sheet includes ID's which are checked by the code and also by the Access-Query which includes the ID's

Best regards

Frederic

Comment: This would be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could start by hiding Excel as screen updating takes a lot of resources:

```
objExcel.Visible = False
```